# Numpy element wise minimum for masked array return valid value instead of masked value

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looping over a large masked array along a specified axis, using element-wise comparison between the current index values and the previous minima.

Below is a simplified example to illustrate the problem. If one of the values is masked and the other is valid, `numpy.minimum()` returns a masked value. Is it possible to change this behaviour, such that the valid value is returned instead?

```
x = np.random.randn(5).round(2)
x[[2,4]] = np.nan
print(x)
print(np.minimum(x[-1], x[-2]))

y = np.ma.masked_invalid(x)
print(y)
print(np.minimum(y[-1], y[-2]))

>>  [-1.21  2.02   nan -0.31   nan]
>>  nan
>>  [-1.21 2.02 -- -0.31 --]
>>  --
```

Instead, I would like the return value to be -0.31.

In this simple example, I could use `y.compressed()` or something like that, but in my case, I have several dimensions, so that doesn't work.

Currently, I use a very high fill_value, which works because there's a physical constraint on the data, but I would like to have a more general solution.

Comment: For this specific case, you could just replace `np.nan` by `np.inf`

Comment: Isn't there a masked version of minimum? Either np.ma.minimum or a method?

Comment: Also look at using `y.filled()`

Comment: @hpaulj That's what I'm doing currently, using `y.filled()` with a very high `fill_value`, but I'm looking for a more general solution.

Comment: I get a runtime warning when trying this minimum with `x` - it doesn't like working with `nan`.  `np.ma.minumum(y...)` gives me a single element masked array.  One way or the other, the `nan` or masking requires special handling.